# chrome-aws-lambda не подключается в Node js

Tags: node.js, express, chromium

Я использую express, Node.js

```
const chrome = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
```

Для подключения chrome использую данный пакет. chrome-aws-lambda.

У меня node.js выдаёт следующую ошибку

```
Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install"
    at Launcher.launch (D:\chronium\now-examples-master\puppeteer-screenshot\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\Launcher.js:119:15)
Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install"
    at Launcher.launch (D:\chronium\now-examples-master\puppeteer-screenshot\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\Launcher.js:119:15)
```

const chrome = require('chrome-aws-lambda'); - это и есть сам chrome .

Знает ли кто в чём может быть проблема ошибки ?

Answer (score 0):

Это версия для консоли

```
hello.js
```

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
console.log('test', event.name)
callback(null, 'hello' + event.name)
}
```

```
invoker.js
```

```
let lambdaFunction = require('./hello')
let functionHandler = 'handler'

let event ={name:'Sergey'}
let context = {}

function callback(error, data) {
console.log(error);
console.log(data);
}

lambdaFunction[functionHandler](event, context, callback)
```